# how to get ONLY values form all KEYS members and form a list - Terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform0.12+

below is a teams.yaml file in the Terraform directory.

```
 ---
 TEAMS:
   - name: dx-example-team2
     roles:
     - GROUP_DATA_ACCESS_READ_WRITE:
       members:
         - ab@ad.com
         - cd@ad.com
     - GROUP_OWNER:
       members:
         - pr@ad.com
```

Hello all,
can someone help me with gettting only values from nested **members** KEY from above YAML file and how to form a list merge of all the values.

**TRIED Terraform Code , but below is just sample i have:**

```
locals {
  teams_file = yamldecode(file("${path.cwd}/teams.yaml"))["TEAMS"]
  all_members = flatten([for team in local.teams_file : [
                          for role in team.roles : {
                            "name" = role
                          }
                          ]
                         
    ])
}

output "sample" {
    value = local.all_members
}
```

**EXPECTED OUTPUT:**

`all_members = [ "ab@ad.com" , "cd@ad.com", "pr@ad.com"]`

Comment: Please explain what's wrong with the current code? Any errors?

Comment: i'm trying with above code and many additions and removals but not able to achieve what i wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case you can just use [spat expression](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/splat):

```
   all_members = flatten(local.teams_file[*].roles[*].members)
```

Comment: @Maric
wow thank you so much. this is what i needed. i feel embarrassed i didn't think about spat expression.